# Any Recommendations, Guidelines around Preparing an Ubuntu 18.04 - cloud-init enabled on vSphere?

Tags: 18.04, vmware, cloud-init

Looking for guidelines, best practices, the Do's and Don'ts around how to prepare a Cloud-init Enabled Ubuntu 18.04 VMware template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the resources I found Answering my own question

https://ubuntu.com/engage/cloud-init-whitepaper
https://debconf17.debconf.org/talks/164/
https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
https://events.linuxfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Cloud-init-The-cross-cloud-magic-sauce_Smith_moser.pdf
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHVhIWifVqU